# how to use git branches to have 2 version of repo, one without a specific folder

Tags: git

I have a repo like this:

```
repo
  folderA
  folderB
  folderC
  folderD
```

I need the master branch to have all these folders. I need `anotherBranch` to ignore `folderD`.

Example. I make modification to folderA in master branch. Then in `anotherBranch` I do git pull and it ignores `folderD` and pulls modification from `folderA` (and B, C if there are any).

I've never used branches and don't know if this is the right solution. But I am looking for any solution to do this in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Ignore as in you have the directory in both branches but if you pull from a branch that modified directory X, you want your branch to skip over those changes on that directory automatically? I don't think that can be done _automatically_. You can `git merge --no-commit` and then checkout that directory to what it was on HEAD and then run `git merge --continue` (or full merge then checkout that directory from HEAD~1 and then amend) but I don't think git can do this on its own

Comment: You could create `anotherBranch` and delete 'folderA'. Then work only from 'master'. After that merge 'master' into 'anotherBranch' or cherry pick every commits. You will conflicts because 'folderA' no longer exists but they were easy to solve. And that should work (if 'folderA' is isolated and no files are moved from or to this folder)

Comment: @Philippe is there somewhere I can read more about this? I don't fully understand what you're explaining. Note that I've never used branches in my life, my only experience is commit/push/pull/clone

Comment: Maybe https://learngitbranching.js.org/ or https://onlywei.github.io/explain-git-with-d3/. Some other documentation : https://gist.github.com/pmiossec/333645ffd7d71670b731 You could also create a dummy git repository (or copy the one you already have) and play inside it (just delete and recreate it when it becomes messy).